# observable from another function

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code

```
var Person = function() {
    firstName = ko.observable();
    lastName = ko.observable();
};

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.personData = ko.observable(new Person());
    self.newPerson = ko.observable(new Person());
    self.savePerson = function() {
        // ajax call
        // self.personData will be empty - why?
        console.log(ko.toJSON(self));
    };

    self.newPerson = function() {
        self.newPerson = ko.observable(new Person()); // this makes the object disappear from the model, dunno why
    };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

where I'm trying to bind a "Person" to a "PersonData" observable and reset that "PersonData" when the new button is clicked, but when I post the model back to the system, it goes empty.

jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/DiegoVieira/SKVRm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your newPerson function has a bug, correct syntax

```
self.personData(new Person());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SKVRm/3/

edit: You were assignig the wrong member, and you were also reassigned it a new observable rather than updating the old observable that is the one that is bound to the personData with binding

Comment: ouch, you're correct! thanks for that. will mark as the answer :)